# Nested sorting between rows and columns

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, rows, multiple-columns, angular-ui-sortable

For a project I would like to use Angular and ui-sortable to be able to sort a list, divided in rows and columns. It is not a table, instead I want to use a div, using bootstrap classes to add rows and col-md classes to appear as a table.
I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raMVqe) that resembles the functionality I want to achieve. Rows can be sorted by drag and drop, with a bit of a hassle. But within a row I can't change the sort order of the columns.

An *example* for the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raMVqe) I am using: I want to be able to change element **A | B to B | A.** And I would also like to be able to move **A | B under C | B**

```
<div class="form-container" ui-sortable="sortableRows" ng-model="filtered">
    <div ng-repeat="row in filtered">
      <div class="row rowborder">
        <div ui-sortable="sortableCols" ng-model="row">
           <div ng-repeat="col in row">
             <div class="col-md-6 colborder">
                 {{col.entry}}
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>           
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution to my problem from another user. There was a structural problem in the HTML. You can find the solution in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raMVqe).

```
<div class="form-container" ui-sortable="sortableRows" ng-model="filtered">
      <div ui-sortable="sortableCols" ng-model="row" ng-repeat="row in filtered" class="row rowborder">
        <div ng-repeat="col in row" class="col-md-6 colborder">
          {{col.entry}}
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```